# How do I send a test request with an image to my deployed model on Google Cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I've uploaded my trained model to the Google Cloud Platform that I trained and exported on lobe.ai. Now I want to send a test request with an image to it so I can use it on my web application. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your tensorflow (*I deduce this from your tags*) model, you have 2 solutions

- Either your [test locally](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#test_your_model_with_local_predictions)
- Or you can [deploy your model on AI Platform in online prediction mode](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#deploy_models_and_versions).

In both cases, you have to submit a [binary](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict) + your features in a JSON instance according with your model inputs